# How do I select a row from a database by matching an ID number in one of the columns?

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I am going to be generating a report in the form of an Excel file using Java and a MySQL database. What I need to happen is to take in an ID number from the UI and then pull the corresponding row from the database that contains that ID number and store it in some sort of data structure. Then I would traverse the data structure and insert each piece of data into it's corresponding cell in the Excel file, doing a few calculations here and there.

So, how would I construct a query that would find and return a row from my database given and ID number and what's the best data structure to keep the returned data in?

Comment: RTLM: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sql_select

Comment: The information you give is rather vague. It is almost impossible to give you an optimal answer related to data structures without knowing what kind of data is stored in the DB. A single integer per record is very different from 5 image BLOBs per record for instance ... The select you will need to use is rather simple though. What have you tried?

Comment: @Ben: some people thought `F` was too harsh, so `(L)inked` it is...

Comment: @RudolphEst The data consists of floats and strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are to use plain-vanilla `jdbc` approach, then I suggest implementing a `prepared statement` to avoid **SQL Injenctions** (regardless how likely that might be).

You will still need to go through all the steps involving in establishing a connection to MySql database:

```
1. Load MySql driver:       Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); 
2. Connect to the database: Connection myConn = DriverManager.getConnection (... URL for your database ...);
```

Then you can create the statement, execute it, and retrieve the result.

Something along these lines:

```
PreparedStatement myStmt = myConn.PreparedStatement("SELECT * FROM YoutTable WHERE ID_Number = ?");
myStmt.setString(1, idStringFromUI);
ResultSet myResults = myStmt.executeQuery();
```

Obviously you need to import `java.sql.*` and take care of all checked exceptions.

This seems to be a good sample of such code: [link](http://www.roseindia.net/jdbc/jdbc-mysql/SelectRecords.shtml)

If you already know all this stuff - please accept my apologies but from your question it wasn't clear.

Answer (score 1):

I think your best bet would be using something like [Hibernate](http://www.hibernate.org/).  It abstracts the actual SQL calls, and returns the result of the query in a "data structure" for you.

Alternatively you could set up your SQL drivers and run the queries yourself, but I imagine you'd be reinventing the wheel in a lot of ways.

As a starting point, your raw SQL query would look something like:

`select * from <yourTable> where <id column> = <your id>`

Comment: Unfortunately, I have to work with what I've got.